# How to get actual exception in SQL transaction when xact_abort is ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, sql-server-2012, try-catch

How can I preserve/retrieve the error state or return the actual error when using `xact_abort ON`?

Currently, when I excecute this stored procedure with an outer transaction already initiated.

```
begin tran
exec TestFK 2
```

I get this generic error which hides the actual error

> The current transaction cannot be committed and cannot support operations that write to the log file. Roll back the transaction.

But when I execute without an external transaction

```
exec TestFK 2
```

I get the proper error.

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__t2__a__3B783965". The conflict occurred in database "XXX", table "dbo.t1", column 'a'.

[Setup Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[TestFK]
@Id int
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON        
    SET xact_abort ON  
    DECLARE @trancount INT
    SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT 
    begin try

        IF @trancount = 0 
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (@Id); -- Foreign key error for @Id = 2

        IF @trancount = 0 
           COMMIT TRANSACTION 
    end try
    begin catch 
      IF Xact_state() <> 0 AND @trancount = 0 
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 

      Exec uspInsErrorInfo -- Here I want to preserve the Error State somehow       
    end catch
END

CREATE TABLE t1 (a INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
CREATE TABLE t2 (a INT NOT NULL REFERENCES t1(a));

INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (3);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (6);
```

Comment: Uh, `IF @trancount = 0 / COMMIT`? Why do you care (and are making decisions based on) what the `@@TRANCOUNT` was BEFORE the `BEGIN TRANSACTION`?

Comment: if `@trancount <> 0` then it means the transaction was initiated outside the stored procedure and the caller will be responsible to commit the transaction

Comment: Isn't that what [`@@NESTLEVEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187371.aspx) is for? Also you know that there are not really anything like nested transactions in SQL Server, right? Have you given Erland's articles a thorough read? Start here: http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling_2005.html

Comment: Actually the SP is called from `C#` code which does two things 1. Calls this SP 2. Updates `SOLR`. We need application level transaction so that if `SOLR` update fails SP can be rolled back. Also this SP is called independantly, so we need transactions in SP as well.

Comment: An easier way would be to pass a parameter when the procedure is called one way vs. another.

Comment: I tried doing just that. Only if I do `SET xact_abort OFF `. Then I am able to call `Exec uspInsErrorInfo;` without rolling it back. But then, it might leave the DB in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution I used was to simply remove the try/catch block in this scenario.

[Since](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.),

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a
>   run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[TestFK]
@Id int
as
begin
    SET NOCOUNT ON        
    SET xact_abort ON  
    DECLARE @trancount INT
    SET @trancount = @@TRANCOUNT 

        IF @trancount = 0 
            BEGIN TRANSACTION

            INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (@Id); -- Foreign key error for @Id = 2
            -- + some other statements
        IF @trancount = 0 
           COMMIT TRANSACTION 
END
```